How to Recover GitHub Account After Losing Access to Authenticator App and Without Recovery Codes?
My GitHub account was linked to an Authenticator app, but I lost access to the app when I replaced my phone. Now I can't log in github without the Authenticator app, and I don't have the recovery codes. Can someone please help me figure out how to log in without the Authenticator app?

This question is similar to: Is there a way to restore Github and Bitbucket 2FA without recovery codes or backup phone number?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Diana, this is not working for me. It's showing git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
